# Add a new column in Python based on the contents of another

Tags: python, function, pandas

I have a data frame of country names and I want to add a column that indicates if it was part of the Muslim ban or not. So, ideally, I would like this:

```
Country Name          Ban
Indonesia             non_muslim_ban
Iran, Islamic Rep.    muslim_ban
Iraq                  non_muslim_ban
Ireland               non_muslim_ban
Libya                 muslim_ban
Liechtenstein         non_muslim_ban
Somalia               muslim_ban
South Africa          non_muslim_ban
Sudan                 muslim_ban
Syrian Arab Republic  muslim_ban
West Bank and Gaza    non_muslim_ban
Yemen, Rep.           muslim_ban
Zambia                non_muslim_ban
Zimbabwe              non_muslim_ban
```

I tried this function and got an error:

```
def muslim_ban(Country_Name):
    if df['Country Name'] in ['Iran', 'Libya', 'Somalia', 'Sudan', 'Syria', 'Yemen']:
        return 'muslim_ban'
    elif df['Country Name'] not in  ['Iran', 'Libya', 'Somalia', 'Sudan', 'Syria', 'Yemen']:
        return 'non_muslim_ban'
`df['muslim_ban'] = df['Country Name'].apply(muslim_ban)


ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Can someone assist please?

Updated to include revised code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with your code.

Firstly, you have space seperated variable name inside the function definition of muslim_ban. So, replace **"Country Name"** with something like **"Country_Name"**

Secondly, you can put miltiple strings in if condition inside a **list** and then use `in` and `not in` operator to check for the existence.

```
def muslim_ban(Country_Name):
    if Country_Name in ['Iran', 'Libya', 'Somalia', 'Sudan', 'Syria', 'Yemen']:
        return 'muslim_ban'
    elif Country_Name not in  ['Iran', 'Libya', 'Somalia', 'Sudan', 'Syria', 'Yemen']:
        return 'non_muslim_ban'

df['muslim_ban'] = df['Country_Name'].apply(muslim_ban)
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked...but when I did this: df_details_by_country['mulsim_ban'] = df_details_by_country.Country Name.apply(muslim_ban), I received another Syntax error right near Apply. Do you know what happened?

Comment: I think the problem was `=` instead of `==` in the second line of the code in the question. This code here solves the problem. Still I think that `elif` is not really necessary.

Comment: I see a **`** character and **Country Name** on the last line.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand

Comment: This is the last line in the code you posted : **`df['mulsim_ban'] = df.Country Name.apply(muslim_ban)**. Notice that line starts with "`" character.

Comment: OK sorry about that. When I run this: 'df['muslim_ban'] = df['Country Name'].apply(muslim_ban)' , I get this error 'ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().'

Comment: @SatishGarg i'm in the process of changing the field names but if i can get some assistance on the running of the function, i'd appreciate it. thank you for your help so far!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138490/discussion-between-lj123456-and-satish-garg).

Answer (score 1):

here are some things that may help.

1. Change Country Name  to CountryName
2. Use '==' for the comparison instead of the assignment operator '='.
3. You don't need an elif as you can just use else return  'non ban'
4. on the very last line of your code there is a single quote at the beginning of your line.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you can have function parameter splitted like this:
`Country Name` ? Maybe this is your syntax error. By the way Syntax error should show you line where you encounter error.

Comment: line one:
 File "<ipython-input-48-03686f8b2c00>", line 1
    def muslim_ban(Country Name):
                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
right at e): of (Country Name):

Answer (score 0):

`ban_muslim = ["Yemen" ,"Syrian Arab Republic" , "Sudan" , "Somalia", "Libya" , "Iran" ]
ban_non_muslim = ["Indonesia","Iraq","Ireland","Liechtenstein","South Africa","Gaza" ,"Zambia","Zimbabwe"]
country_name = str(input("please enter your country name: "))`

if country_name in ban_muslim :
     print ("you entered banned muslim country ",country_name)
elif country_name in ban_non_muslim:
     print("you entered banned muslim country " ,country_name)
else:
    print (" you enterd unavailable name")